# Power Query Assign group identification every n number of elements

Tags: powerquery, fill

I have a CSV file that I need to import with PowerQuery. I want to assign groups of 3 and give them a name or room number. I know it is possible to use the Table.FillUp function to fill the values up. But I don't know how to assign a variable or another method to change the classroom identification

Parts of M code

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Fila", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "CadaV3", each if Number.Mod([Fila], 3)=0 then 1 else 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your student IDs are consecutive, per your example, then you can use `Number.IntegerDivide`:

```
#"Added Room Number" = Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Room Number", each Number.IntegerDivide([studentId] - 1,3))
```

Alternatively, add an Index column, and use that similarly:

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Previous Step", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Room Number" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Room Number", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index] - 1,3))
```

Comment: Thanks you! Very good and simple solution. I need letters to identify the classrooms. I am going to generate a table with a sequence and letter to combine them.

Comment: = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Room Number", each Character.FromNumber(65+Number.IntegerDivide([Index] - 1,3)))

Answer (score 0):

Depending on only the `assign groups of 3` direction, with no dependency on Student ID or Index columns:

*good for up to 26 classrooms -- if it might be more, we need a different approach*

```
et
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Students"]}[Content],

//generate a list of classrooms "by threes"
    classRooms = List.Transform(
        List.Range(
            List.Sort(
                List.Repeat({1..
                    Number.RoundAwayFromZero(Table.RowCount(Source)/3,0)},3)),
            0,Table.RowCount(Source)), each Character.FromNumber(_+64)),

//add the classroomID column
    roomAssignment = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(Source) & {classRooms},
        type table[StudentID=Int64.Type, Name=text, ClassroomID=text])
   
in
    roomAssignment
```